# Arrow function to callback function for IE support

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Since IE won't accept my arrow function, I am trying to convert the below function to a callback-function instead:

Origional function:

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
}
```

Callback function:

```
function getKeyByValue(object, value) {
  Object.keys(object).find( function(key) {
      return object[key] === value;
  })
}
```

However, the new function is not returning anything. What am I missing?

Comment: [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) is not supported by IE. Use `filter` instead.

Comment: or the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) in that same page (for IE9+)

Comment: Thanks. But the above function doesn't even work in chrome, so something else must be wrong.